# Definition function in LaTeX Tcolorboxed Poster

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, theorems, posters, definition

I'd like to create a `\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{definition}{Definition}{...}` like this:

[image: DEFPOSTER]

"Title of the definition" and "Statement of the definition" must be manually inserted.

Please Someone help me about the code.

(P.S.: Perhaps I must created a newenvironment, but I don't know how)

The code below and thank you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\title{TCBPOSTER}
\author{???}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{Tcolorboxed Posters}
\section{Definition: \LaTeX--function}

\subsection{With Poster of Tcolorbox--package}
\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {spacing=2mm,columns=1,rows=1},
coverage = {height=3cm,
interior style={top color=yellow,bottom color=yellow!50!red},
},
boxes = {sharp corners=downhill,arc=3mm,boxrule=1mm,
colback=white,colframe=cyan,
title style={left color=black,right color=cyan},
fonttitle=\bfseries}
]
\posterbox[adjusted title=Definition chapetr.section.subsection.definition\_number (Title of the definition)] {column=1,row=1,span=1}{The height of the box must be automatically calculated by LaTeX according to the length of the text inside. It's possible to do it?}
\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a `tcbposter` you need to fix a `height` or it will use a `default` one. And a `tcbposter` is not breakable.

If you want to fix the height automatically you can use a `tcbraster` or just a `tcolorbox` inside another box. Second option is what is shown in following code.

A `\newtcbtheorem` has been defined for `Definitions`. The first use shows this environment alone and the second shows the effect of including it inside an external `tcolobox` which provides the yellow background. As the second example is formed by two nested boxes, the result won't break between pages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{outerbox}{enhanced, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt, interior style={top color=yellow, bottom color=yellow!50!red}, notitle}
    
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{mydef}{Definition}{%
    enhanced, sharp corners=downhill, arc=3mm, 
    boxrule=1mm, colback=white, colframe=cyan, 
    title style={left color=black, right color=cyan}, fonttitle=\bfseries,
    separator sign none,
    description delimiters parenthesis
    }{def}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Tcolorboxed Posters}
\section{Definition: \LaTeX--function}

\subsection{With Poster of Tcolorbox--package}

\begin{mydef}{Title of the definition}{myfirstlabel}
The height of the box must be automatically calculated by LaTeX according to the length of the text inside. It's possible to do it?
\end{mydef}

\begin{outerbox}
\begin{mydef}{Title of the definition}{mysecondlabel}
The height of the box must be automatically calculated by LaTeX according to the length of the text inside. It's possible to do it?
\end{mydef}
\end{outerbox}

The definition~\ref{def:myfirstlabel} has no external box while the definition~\ref{def:mysecondlabel} although this one won't be breakable because they are nested boxes.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much